# Journey Builder Changes

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio

If I make some changes to the HTML emails in Email Studio - to get those changes to reflect in the active journey, do I have to create a new version?

If I do that - will the activating of that journey also be the time of send?  I want to queue my sending at 9:00am but want to make the changes now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most asked questions and there has been recent updates regarding how to update the content/emails in journey.

**Option 1)** With the latest update, in the active/running journey you can hover on top of the email activity and click on **View and Update activity**. Once you're in the dialogue box, please reselect the same email and hit **save**.

[image]

> Note: The hover function might take sometime. Please refresh your browser if it takes too much time.

**Option 2)** The journey emails are essentially triggered send emails, so another way to update is to navigate to the **Interactions > Triggered Emails** in Email Studio. You'll then see **Journey Builder Sends** folder and you'll have to navigate to the right journey and right version number. Then it is matter of choosing the right Trigger Definition where you pause, publish and restart that email trigger.

> Note: Pausing, publishing and restarting the trigger will put the
>   contacts in queue and won't affect the journey as long as you restart
>   asap.